# Infinite loop iterating a column of an array in Python

Tags: python

I have an issue iterating through an array of 6x8 elements. Somehow I get an infinite loop. But I don't see any logical mistakes.

```
array=[[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]]

    i=1
    j=1
    while i<=6:
        if "O" in array[i][j]:
            i = i + 1
            if i > 4:
                print("Game over")
```

I can actually put some input into the array. The Array represents something like a chess field. I want to count in every turn how often an `"O"` is occurred in the column 1. If it occurs more then 3 times, it should print `"Game over"`. But the loop becomes infinite.

Comment: Try shift line  i=i+1 up outside the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is infinite because the `i` variable is not incremented, if `"O" in array[i][j]` condition is `False`.

Besides, there is a better way to iterate arrays in Python:

```
def check_column_cells(array, column):
    counter = 0

    for row in array:
        if row[column] == "O":
            counter += 1
            if (counter > 3):
                print("Game over")
                return counter

    return counter

# Check the 2nd column (the indices start from 0)
print(check_column_cells(array, 1))
```

If you still would like to use indices, apply the increment operations:

```
def check_column_cells(array, column):
    counter = 0

    r = 0
    while r < len(array):
        if array[r][column] == "O":
            counter += 1
            if (counter > 3):
                print("Game over")
                return counter
        r += 1

    return counter

# Check the 2nd column (the indices start from 0)
print(check_column_cells(array, 1))
```

Note, I have skipped security checks for clarity's sake. In the functions above, you should check if the column index is in the available range, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You only increment **i** in the **if**. You need to increment **i** at **each loop**.

I recommend you to use a loop in a collection.

[Lists of lists](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

```
list_of_lists = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for list in list_of_lists:
    for x in list:
        print x
```